# how can i remove duplicates this jsonarray in java help need combine the department list if name is equal other wise set into separate json object

Tags: java

```
[ContactVo{ emailId='rmartinez@s-gins.com', firstName='Rose', 
lastName='Martinez', department=[Department{departmentId=1 }]}, 
ContactVo{, emailId='rmartinez@s-gins.com', firstName='Rose',
 lastName='Martinez',department=[Department{departmentId=2}]},
 ContactVo{emailId='rmartinez@s-gins.com', firstName='Rose', 
lastName='Martinez',department=[Department{departmentId=3}]}, ContactVo{
 emailId='rmartinez@s-gins.com', firstName='Rose', lastName='Martinez',
 department=[Department{departmentId=4}]}, 
ContactVo{emailId='CarrierPayables@higginbotham.net', firstName='null',
 lastName='null',department=[Department{departmentId=5}]}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). This is not valid JSON. The body of a question should include the question, the title is a summary of the content of the question.

Comment: [ContactVo{contactDetailsId=null, createdAt=null, createdBy=null, departmentId='1', emailId='ronjaeck@nixonagency.com', firstName='Ron', lastName='Jaeck', producerId=null, status=null, updatedAt=null, updatedBy=null}, ContactVo{contactDetailsId=null, createdAt=null, createdBy=null, departmentId='2', emailId='ronjaeck@nixonagency.com', firstName='Ron', lastName='Jaeck', producerId=null, status=null, updatedAt=null, updatedBy=null}]

Comment: If you paste your JSON into https://jsonlint.com/ you can check if it is valid.